# Insert several lines in field collection programmatically

Tags: nodes, entities

I have a problem with field collection and entity reference fields. I have a field collection called 'field_co_intervenant' and i want to add several entities in this field collection and after saved my node. But i got an error with the index i think, because when the node is saved, there is just one reference entity in my field collection. You can see the code here :

$intervenant is the array of my 'nid'.

```
if(!empty($intervenant)) {
    //Create entity
    $fieldcollection = entity_create('field_collection_item', array('field_name' => 'field__doc_fc_intervenant_tab'));
    //Attach entity
    $fieldcollection->setHostEntity('node', $node);
    //Fill field
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($intervenant as $val) {
        if($val != null) {
            $fieldcollection->field_fc_intervenant_tab[LANGUAGE_NONE][$i]['target_id'] = $val;
            $i++;
        }
    }

    //Save entity
    $fieldcollection->save();
}
```

How can i save all my values in the field collection and not just one ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First be sure that that field in your field collection field setting accept multi value** then try save your item with

```
  $node->field_fc_intervenant_tab['und'][] = array('value' => $field_collection_item->item_id,
    'revision_id' => $field_collection_item->revision_id,);
```

and finally be something like

```
if(!empty($intervenant)) {    

    // you should have $node here
      $field_collection_item = NULL;
      $field_collection_item = entity_create('field_collection_item', array('field_name' => ''field__doc_fc_intervenant_tab '));
      $field_collection_item->setHostEntity('node', $node);
      $field_collection_item->save(TRUE);
          foreach ($intervenant as $val) {
             if($val != null) {
      $node->field_fc_intervenant_tab['und'][] = array('value' => $field_collection_item->item_id,
        'revision_id' => $field_collection_item->revision_id,);
}
}
    $fieldcollection->save();
}
```

Comment: @Remi you're welcome ;) +1 it :D